# Cannot suppress notification when a client connects to my vino server VNC

Tags: vnc, notifications, bodhi

I am using `vino-server` in Bodhi Linux, an Ubuntu derivative which, in my experience, for most purposes (but not all) works the same as Ubuntu.

When a client connects to my PC I get a notification.
I want to disable them.
The client is TigerVNC in Win 10, but I guess that is irrelevant.

I have set `org.gnome.Vino notify-on-connect` to `false`.
Since setting this from the command line did not seem to alter what I see in `dconf-editor` (at least immediately, I didn't tinker further with this), I also set this in `dconf-editor`, and rebooted.

I have this.
I don't know where else to look for.

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.Vino
org.gnome.Vino prompt-enabled false
org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
org.gnome.Vino use-alternative-port false
org.gnome.Vino disable-background false
org.gnome.Vino disable-xdamage false
org.gnome.Vino alternative-port uint16 5900
org.gnome.Vino icon-visibility 'client'
org.gnome.Vino authentication-methods ['none']
org.gnome.Vino network-interface ''
org.gnome.Vino notify-on-connect false
org.gnome.Vino mailto ''
org.gnome.Vino lock-screen-on-disconnect false
org.gnome.Vino use-upnp false
org.gnome.Vino vnc-password 'keyring'
org.gnome.Vino view-only false
```

How can I disable these notifications?

It seems unlikely to do that at the vino level (even if there is a setting for that, apparently!).
Perhaps with handling of notifications has some type of filtering.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep notif
ii  gir1.2-notify-0.7:amd64               0.7.9-1ubuntu2                      amd64        sends desktop notifications to a notification daemon (Introspection files)
ii  libnotify4:amd64                      0.7.9-1ubuntu2                      amd64        sends desktop notifications to a notification daemon
ii  libstartup-notification0:amd64        0.12-6                              amd64        library for program launch feedback (shared library)
ii  libuv1:amd64                          1.34.2-1ubuntu1.3                   amd64        asynchronous event notification library - runtime library
ii  libzephyr4:amd64                      3.1.2-1build3                       amd64        Project Athena's notification service - non-Kerberos libraries
ii  notification-daemon                   3.20.0-4                            amd64        daemon for displaying passive pop-up notifications
ii  vlc-plugin-notify:amd64               3.0.9.2-1                           amd64        LibNotify plugin for VLC
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy-paste from [Vino's home page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vino):

Vino was the GNOME desktop sharing server. It is now archived and unmaintained - please use [gnome-remote-desktop](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-remote-desktop) instead!

Comment: I am not using Gnome, but Moksha.
As per [this](https://desktopi18n.wordpress.com/2021/12/06/gnome-remote-desktop/), 
apparently gnome-remote-desktop does not work with non-Gnome, I may try it anyway.
But I am very familiar with vino...